# How do you return the timestamp from Cassandra when using Python and CQL?

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

When running the query.

```
"select * from temperature_by_day"
```

Cassandra is returning a string '\x00\x00\x017\xa7\xea\x9e\x00' for the timestamp.

If I query from cqlsh on the server it returns the dates I've set.

I've read this post: [How to retrieve the timestamp from cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346839/how-to-retrieve-the-timestamp-from-cassandra?answertab=votes#tab-top)

It states "It's not recommended to use column Cassandra timestamps directly in client code;".

Why?

The tutorial here states to query the timestamp directly.

http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

So is the proper thing to do to add an additional timestamp that is not part of the primary key and query against this timestamp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Datastax Python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/) supports the timestamp type. If you want to learn how to deserialize it check out the [DataType.deserialize](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqltypes.py#L513) method:

```
return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int64_unpack(byts) / 1000.0)
```

Comment: I seem to be having difficulty installing the cassandra-driver. I'm stuck. It's complaining about    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsal
l

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was able to get the driver installed and running.